Java applet code has scale variable for sizing window not sure what it's for
I am having a bit of difficulty understanding what the purpose of this code might be. I put an applet into a Java decompiler and this is the code. Specifically, the line where it is setting the viewCenter is confusing. I am not sure what the purpose of this.scale might be.
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class SeekFlee extends Applet implements Runnable {
  private Thread update;

  Seeker seeker;

  Seeker fleer;

  float scale = 15.0F;

  Vector3 viewCenter;

  int framesSinceTouch;

  Image canvasimage;

  Graphics canvasG;

  Graphics myG;

  int wxsize;

  int wysize;

  public void init() {
    super.init();
    this.wxsize = (getSize()).width;
    this.wysize = (getSize()).height;
    resize(this.wxsize, this.wysize);
    this.canvasimage = createImage(this.wxsize, this.wysize);
    this.canvasG = this.canvasimage.getGraphics();
    this.myG = getGraphics();
    this.viewCenter = new Vector3(this.wxsize / 2.0F * this.scale, this.wysize / 2.0F * this.scale, 0.0F);
    this.seeker = new Seeker();
    this.fleer = new Seeker();
    resetSeekers();
  }

  public boolean handleEvent(Event event) {
    boolean returnValue = false;
    return returnValue;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    SeekFlee app = new SeekFlee();
    app.init();
    app.start();
    f.add("Center", app);
    f.resize(515, 300);
    f.show();
  }

  public void start() {
    if (this.update == null) {
      this.update = new Thread(this);
      this.update.start();
    } 
  }

  public void stop() {
    if (this.update != null && this.update.isAlive())
      this.update.stop(); 
    this.update = null;
  }

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      repaint();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(33L);
      } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {}
    } 
  }

  private void showbuffer() {
    this.myG.drawImage(this.canvasimage, 0, 0, this);
  }

  static final Color bgColor = new Color(0.9F, 0.9F, 0.6F);

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.canvasG.setColor(bgColor);
    this.canvasG.fillRect(0, 0, this.wxsize, this.wysize);
    updateSeekers();
    this.canvasG.setColor(Color.black);
    this.canvasG.drawRect(0, 0, this.wxsize - 1, this.wysize - 1);
    showbuffer();
  }

  public void updateSeekers() {
    this.seeker.update();
    this.seeker.draw(this.canvasG, this.scale);
    this.fleer.update();
    this.fleer.draw(this.canvasG, this.scale);
    this.fleer.touch = this.seeker.touch;
    this.framesSinceTouch = this.seeker.touch ? (this.framesSinceTouch + 1) : 0;
    if (this.framesSinceTouch > 15)
      resetSeekers(); 
  }

  public void resetSeekers() {
    this.seeker.position.setUnitRandom();
    this.seeker.position.setScale(17.0F, this.seeker.position);
    this.seeker.position.setSum(this.viewCenter, this.seeker.position);
    this.seeker.position.z = 0.0F;
    this.seeker.velocity.setUnitRandom();
    this.seeker.velocity.setScale(this.seeker.maxSpeed, this.seeker.velocity);
    this.seeker.velocity.z = 0.0F;
    this.seeker.target.set(this.viewCenter);
    this.seeker.touch = false;
    this.fleer.seek = false;
    this.fleer.position.set(this.seeker.position);
    this.fleer.velocity.set(this.seeker.velocity);
    this.fleer.target.set(this.viewCenter);
    this.fleer.touch = false;
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
  }
}

Vector3 is a class representing a 3D vector.
import java.util.Random;

public class Vector3 {
  public float x;

  public float y;

  public float z;

  public static final Vector3 zero = new Vector3();

  public Vector3() {
    setZero();
  }

  public Vector3(float x, float y, float z) {
    set(x, y, z);
  }

  public void set(Vector3 that) {
    this.x = that.x;
    this.y = that.y;
    this.z = that.z;
  }

  public void set(float x, float y, float z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  public void setZero() {
    set(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
  }

  public boolean equals(Vector3 that) {
    if (this.x != that.x || 
      this.y != that.y || 
      this.z != that.z)
      return false; 
    return true;
  }

  public boolean equalsZero() {
    return !(this.x != 0.0F || this.y != 0.0F || this.z != 0.0F);
  }

  public float magnitude() {
    return (float)Math.sqrt(magnitudeSquared());
  }

  public float magnitudeSquared() {
    return this.x * this.x + 
      this.y * this.y + 
      this.z * this.z;
  }

  public float dot(Vector3 that) {
    return this.x * that.x + 
      this.y * that.y + 
      this.z * that.z;
  }

  static Random generator = new Random();

  public void setUnitRandom() {
    do {
      this.x = generator.nextFloat() * 2.0F - 1.0F;
      this.y = generator.nextFloat() * 2.0F - 1.0F;
      this.z = generator.nextFloat() * 2.0F - 1.0F;
    } while (magnitudeSquared() > 1.0F);
  }

  public float approximateLength() {
    float a = this.x;
    if (a < 0.0F)
      a = -a; 
    float b = this.y;
    if (b < 0.0F)
      b = -b; 
    float c = this.z;
    if (c < 0.0F)
      c = -c; 
    if (a < b) {
      float t = a;
      a = b;
      b = t;
    } 
    if (a < c) {
      float t = a;
      a = c;
      c = t;
    } 
    return a * 0.9375F + (b + c) * 0.375F;
  }

  private static Vector3 distTemp = new Vector3();

  public float distance(Vector3 v) {
    synchronized (distTemp) {
      distTemp.setDiff(this, v);
      return distTemp.magnitude();
    } 
  }

  public float approximateDistance(Vector3 v) {
    synchronized (distTemp) {
      distTemp.setDiff(this, v);
      return distTemp.approximateLength();
    } 
  }

  public void setSum(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
    a.x += b.x;
    a.y += b.y;
    a.z += b.z;
  }

  public void setDiff(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
    a.x -= b.x;
    a.y -= b.y;
    a.z -= b.z;
  }

  public void setScale(float a, Vector3 b) {
    this.x = a * b.x;
    this.y = a * b.y;
    this.z = a * b.z;
  }

  public void setCross(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
    set(a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, 
        a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, 
        a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x);
  }

  public void setInterp(float blend, Vector3 v0, Vector3 v1) {
    v0.x += blend * (v1.x - v0.x);
    v0.y += blend * (v1.y - v0.y);
    v0.z += blend * (v1.z - v0.z);
  }

  public void setNormalize() {
    float m = magnitude();
    if (m != 0.0F)
      setScale(1.0F / m, this); 
  }

  public void setApproximateNormalize() {
    float m = approximateLength();
    if (m != 0.0F)
      setScale(1.0F / m, this); 
  }

  public void setApproximateTruncate(float threshold) {
    float length = approximateLength();
    if (length > threshold)
      setScale(threshold / length, this); 
  }
}


edited to provide more details

Java applets are no longer supported. Not sure why you care.

I'm trying to convert some older code into a different language @ElliottFrisch

Well we can't tell based on one line of code either.

What package is Vector3? You should provide more details and explain what you are trying to achieve. Edit the question to add details.

Looks like it's trying to establish the dead center of the current context (whatever UI object this is). scale may come from a scaling value associated with some preset size of the overall UI. That having been said... I'm only guessing. If you provided more code, you might get a more definitive answer, as opposed to speculation in a comment.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@MarsAtomic edited to provide more details
